# OpenMp and Qt Creator

Tags: openmp, qt-creator

So I am a newbie to Qt Creator, and was looking for a good step by step instruction in changing from the default clang compiler to use the clang-omp compiler for the purpose of using openMp in qt creator. I already change the compiler to point to clang-omp as instructed by qt docs, but for some reason qt still uses the default xcode clang compiler to build my code; thereby not accepting the "omp.h" include statement. I also included these flag. QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -openmp QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -openmp LIBS += -lgomp

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong. Although I set the g++ compile as a new default in the kit option of the system preference page, I did not set g++ as the default through the project options in the side panel of main.cpp interface. For some reason this meant that I was still using qt's default clang compiler instead of the new default compiler I set in kit.